# Labeling data based on string value in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, contains

I have a dataframe with 8000 rows, where column `job_name` contains strings with a short "job header" (see below).
I created different lists containing the individual job positions I want to group.

```
job_hilfskraft = ['bretreuungskraft', 'pflegehilfskraft', 'pflegehelfer', 'krankenpflegehelfer','altenpflegerhelfer', 'pflegeassistent','pflegeassistenz','pflegehilfskräfte', 'pflegeassistenten', 'altenpflegehilfskraft', 'pflegeassistentin','altenpflegehelfer']
job_fachkraft = ['pflegefachkraft', 'altenpfleger','pflegefachkräfte','altenpflegerin', 'pflegekraft', 'krankenpfleger', 'krankenpfleger', 'altenpflegerin', 'altenpflegefachkraft', 'pflegemitarbeiter']
job_leitung = ['pflegedienstleitung', 'pflegedienstleiter', 'wohnbereichsleiter', 'einrichtungsleiter']
job_sonstige = ['küchenhilfskraft', 'reinigungskraft', 'küchenleiter', 'servicekraft', 'spülkraft', 'empfangskraft']
```

Example for a string including the job position.

```
    job_name
0   Küchenhilfskraft in Teilzeit gesucht!
1   Examinierter Krankenpfleger in ambulanter Station
```

Desired output:

```
        job_name                                        job_label
0   Küchenhilfskraft in Teilzeit gesucht!               sonstige
1   Examinierter Krankenpfleger in ambulanter Station   fachkraft
```

I use

```
df['job_label'] = ""

df['job_label'][df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_hilfskraft))] = 'hilfskraft'
df['job_label'][df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_leitung))] = 'leitung'
df['job_label'][df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_sonstige))] = 'sonstige'
df['job_label'][df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_fachkraft))] = 'fachkraft'
```

But it doesn't assign the labels to the corresponding rows or only a few... (<5% of the rows)

I also get the message for each "contains" line:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your current problem.

```
df['job_label'] = ""

df.loc[df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_hilfskraft)), 'job_label'] = 'hilfskraft'
df.loc[df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_leitung)), 'job_label'] = 'leitung'
df.loc[df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_sonstige)), 'job_label'] = 'sonstige'
df.loc[df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_fachkraft)), 'job_label'] = 'fachkraft'
```

I would probably have written it like this:

```
lookup = {'hilfskraft': ['bretreuungskraft', 'pflegehilfskraft', 'pflegehelfer', 'krankenpflegehelfer','altenpflegerhelfer', 'pflegeassistent','pflegeassistenz','pflegehilfskräfte', 'pflegeassistenten', 'altenpflegehilfskraft', 'pflegeassistentin','altenpflegehelfer'],
'fachkraft': ['pflegefachkraft', 'altenpfleger','pflegefachkräfte','altenpflegerin', 'pflegekraft', 'krankenpfleger', 'krankenpfleger', 'altenpflegerin', 'altenpflegefachkraft', 'pflegemitarbeiter'],
'leitung': ['pflegedienstleitung', 'pflegedienstleiter', 'wohnbereichsleiter', 'einrichtungsleiter'],
'sonstige': ['küchenhilfskraft', 'reinigungskraft', 'küchenleiter', 'servicekraft', 'spülkraft', 'empfangskraft']}


df['job_label'] = ""

for replace, keywords in lookup.items():
    for k in keywords:
        df.loc[df.job_name.str.contains(k, case=False, regex=False), 'job_label'] = replace
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. Same result as before. Actually, I just realized that it only assigns 'hilfskraft' to some rows (but not all where it should), and none of the other labels are assigned.

Comment: If you are getting the same warning as before there is probably additional context to this problem which you are not sharing. Does `df.job_name.str.contains('|'.join(job_hilfskraft))` generate a boolean series which appears correct?

Comment: Sorry, indeed the warning disappeared.

Comment: I would have chosen to do a nested loop approach, I've edited it into the question. Might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but returns exactly the same result.

Comment: If you're sure that the strings are correct I would expect that to work no matter what - there might be a unicode problem you can fix with `regex=False` in the `str.contains()`

Comment: Also looking at your example you might also wish to set `case=False` in the `str.contains()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196111/discussion-between-maeaex1-and-cjr).